# Issue while using google maps android api with tab activity : map hanging

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

i implemented google map android api in Tab Activity, it implemented successfully, i have two tab for Map. when i try to change activity from one map to second map that time map is hanged, i can not use map functionalists like zoom or everything. How to solve it.  I am using this code:

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_detail)).getMap();
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

If you have any idea than please help me.

Comment: The idea is not to use deprecated `TabActivity` and use `FragmentActivity` to manage your fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently troubleshooting some strange issues surrounding the Google Maps API v1 and the TabActivity in the [GPSTest app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.gpstest), likely due to the reason that TabActivity has been deprecated for quite some time.  My conclusion was that TabActivity is no longer a reliable solution for this type of application.

Therefore, I would recommend changing to using [ActionBarSherlock (ABS)](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

I recently overhauled GPSTest to use ABS, Fragments, and Google Maps API v2, and its open-source on Github, so it should be a good starting point for your app:
https://github.com/barbeau/gpstest/wiki

Note that as of July 3rd the new GPSTest v2 is still rolling out to Google Play users, and therefore you may not see the new version on Google Play yet.